# Checking your old downvotes

Tags: support, down-votes

I wanted to check my ancient down votes to see if things have improved:

I tried to make a [query on data.se](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/q/115710/) to find my downvotes:

```
select Name as Type, PostId as [Post Link]
from Votes
join VoteTypes on VoteTypeId = VoteTypes.Id
where UserId = ##UserId##​
```

but it only shows favorites.  I guess it makes sense that we can't view other people's votes, but since we can make data.se accounts and it already looks up our userid based on email hash, can it not also check that we are only looking at our own votes?

Alternatively, is there some other way to see on which questions I still have down votes?

It's hard to check if someone has fixed their answer / question if I don't know what their answer / question is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can figure that out by going to https://math.stackexchange.com/reputation and looking for "(-1)".

More details here: [How do I audit my reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005)

Comment: If someone has been active for many days and wants to find an old downvote this can be a real hassle.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Jack wants a list, and this gives it. As to your concern, a little bit of scripting would help cut down the hassle, once you have the complete list, I suppose.

Comment: In fact you can find out the classification of the reputation change. Downvoting is 3 (it is in that same page you link)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Right, searching for (-1) rather than 3 is probably faster though...

Comment: True, but vote type 3 is more useful for an SQL query :-)

Comment: I don't think data.se will give you any info about individual downvotes, as that is sensitive information. So, unfortunately, the reputation link might be the only way.

Comment: That sure as hell sounds reasonable. Shame :-)

Comment: Thanks!  I added a simple javascript/bookmarklet filter below.

Answer (score 4):

Using Aryabhata's hint, I put a bookmarklet at http://www.ms.uky.edu/~jack/mse.html -- to use it drag the "My Downvotes" link to the toolbar right below the address bar on your browser.  It pulls out the downvotes you cast on *answers* (as opposed to the upvotes and accepts you did, and the downvotes done to you) and links to the answers.  It doesn't give names, but it is very fast and simple.

It does not display downvotes on *deleted* answers, or on *any* questions.  As far as I can tell, those downvotes are permanent and/or lost.

Comment: I don't have a toolbar below the address bar?

Comment: @Jyrki: What browser are you using?

Comment: @J.M. Firefox ver 7. This is probably configurable. I vaguely recall getting rid of a bunch of toolbars, because they took up too much space on the small laptop screen. As things are now, there is nothing between the address bar and the viewing area.

Comment: Clicking Jack's script only gives me the usual (?) listing from the reputation page with all my reputation changes sorted by date and (presumably) ID# of the question.

Comment: @Jyrki: Oh yeah, the bookmark toolbar is disabled by default in version 7; you can enable it in View > Toolbars and then checking "Bookmarks Toolbar".

Comment: @J.M. Ok, I could now drag Jack's link to that area. The output of that script didn't change though.

Comment: @Jyrki: I need to click the bookmarklet twice if I'm not already on the reputation summary page. The first time I get to the usual view, the second time Jack's script reads out the answers I downvoted and provides links to them. (I'm using FF, too). Maybe this simple thing does the job for you, too?

Comment: Thanks @t.b. Didn't Jack initially tell us to click twice? I was confused and assumed that he told us to "doubleclick". Apparently there is a difference :-)

Comment: @Jyrki: Yes he did. If it's any consolation, I first had the same misinterpretation :)

Comment: Nice! It worked for me.